# How to check if particular software is installed using java, Linux

Tags: java, linux

I'm writing an application in java. In order to work my code properly, I want to check whether several software are installed. (This should be done in the java code itself.) 
How can I do that?

This is a Linux system.

There are similar questions, but not exactly what I want.

[Check if a program is installed on a linux machine from a java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870398/check-if-a-program-is-installed-on-a-linux-machine-from-a-java-applet)

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal way of doing it.

You can use one of following approaches

- Use java bindings for particular package manager for your platform if they exist.
- Use one of the system tools like `locate`, `whereis`, etc. (which you didn't like)
- Implement your own *installed package* detection, according to your requirements